# What difference between two discharge resistors in two circuits?

Tags: resistors, discharge

When I search for 220VAC led indicator, I found two circuits

one from here [circuit 1](http://www.turbokeu.com/myprojects/acled.htm)

[image: circuit 1]

another here [circuit 2](http://circuitscheme.com/led-indicator-for-220v-ac-mains.html)

[image: circuit 2]

The purpose of R1 from two circuits for discharge C1 when main AC off, but is there any difference between two type of connections? In circuit 1 R1 connect between two AC line, in citcuit 2 R1 connect parallel with C1

Comment: to analyze this properly , you must compute the impedance, ripple current , voltage rating and power dissipation of each component to determine if the values are correct., then choose full wave.  None of these look OK as it is.

Comment: Normally I'm not concern about a 50 or 60 Hz flickering,
In some case I used two LEDs in anti parallel (using a second LED on D1 instead of a regular diode).
The LEDs protect each other.
Bye
Rob.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Circuit 1 will light the LED on one half cycle only. This may result in some visible flicker. Circuit 2 improves on this by using a full-wave bridge recifier to light the LED on both half-cycles.

There's no real effective difference for the R1 connection. In Circuit 1, C1 is discharging through the load, and in Circuit 2, it's discharging across the cap directly. That said I'd prefer the way it's done in Circuit 2, as it localizes the discharge loop.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem I would have with circuit 1 is that if the LED fails open (a quite typical [failure mode](https://www.stanley-components.com/data/technical_note/TN006_e.pdf) of LEDs), the discharge circuit will stop working.

[image]

The irony is that the moment the LED fails is exactly when the end user / technician may be opening the case to troubleshoot the device, exposing them to the dangerous voltage.